# Go with t-test or Mann-Whitney U test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I'm measuring performance of 2 methods (`method_A` and `method_B`) that try to satisfy customers demands. Both methods produce results between 0 (none of the demands were satisfied) and 1 (all demands were satisfied). Also, both methods run for a certain amount of `Time` and, after that, they return best possible solution.

I've generated 30 datasets and solved each one with `method_A` and `method_B` with different `Time` limits. The results are summarized below:

[image]

My goal is to do some hypothesis testing with the results.
I've considered to do a `t-test` but before that I've decided to do some normality tests.
Results below:

Histogram of `method_A` and `method_B`
[image]

Q-Q Plot and Shapiro–Wilk test for `method_A`
[image]

Q-Q Plot and Shapiro–Wilk test for `method_B`
[image]

For small `Time` values data seem to follow normal distribution so I think that `t-test` can be done. Am I right?
However, when `Time` values are large the distribution seem to become non normal.
This is especially visible when average results of both methods are close to 1:

- `Time` equal to 80 and 90 for `method_A`
- `Time` equal to 140 and 150 for `method_B`

So the question is: For these scenarios should I do `Mann-Whitney U Test`? 
For some reason, doing 2 different tests (`t-test` and `Mann-Whitney U Test`) for same data doesn't seem right...

Overall, what is the best way to do hypothesis testing with this kind of data?

Answer (score 0):

I would just use the Mann-Whitney test on the raw data. From the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test):

> Unlike the t-test it does not require the assumption of normal
>   distributions. It is nearly as efficient as the t-test on normal
>   distributions.

In other words, even if you overcome the hurdle of determining exactly in which cases the normal assumption is valid, you don't really gain a lot of power (plus you lose the ability to compare results for different times).

Comment: Yeah, I'm also inclined to follow the "safety first" principle and just use `Mann-Whitney test` and be done with. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to treat the data for each time as a different hypothesis test, then there's probably no theoretical reason why you can't use different tests for different data sets.  But practically speaking, it may be easier to use one test.  Also, because the t-test and Mann-Whitney test very different hypotheses, summarizing results of these different tests can be tricky.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So what would you recommend?

Comment: Mann-Whitney would be better for what you're trying to do.